# In assassin's creed, how do I get viewpoints on the map?

Tags: assassins-creed

I am playing assassin's creed and when I go to the map no viewpoints show up and when I go up to where they usually are, they don't allow me to synchronise.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you post a screenshot of the map to clarify your question?

Comment: This sounds like a technical issue which requires much more information to troubleshoot. As far as I can remembers, all Assassin's Creed games have made viewpoints themselves available by default on the map (other markers are hidden until nearby viewpoints are synchronized, though).